# Using ng-class to enable pagination

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'd like to create a pagination control that shows the user what page they are on.  I'm having trouble using ng-class to style the page links properly.

After I get the count of the data, I setup $scope.pages to be [0,1,2..n] where n is the count / itemsPerPage.  The html looks like this...

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-click="prevPage()"><a>«</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages"
        ng-class="(page==$index)? 'active' : ''"
        ng-click="selectedPage(page)"><a>{{page+1}}</a></li>
    <li ng-click="nextPage()"><a>»</a></li>
</ul>
```

But this markup results in all `<li>` getting the active class.  I can see with debugging that $index is advancing within the li's, and I can see that page is the expected value (I can also see the style looks right when I hard-code it), so why doesn't the conditional styling work as I have it above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not be evaluating the expression against `$index`. The way you have it written, it will _always_ be true.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm seeing (always true), but what else would I compare it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be evaluating the expression against `$index`. If you desk check the repeat loop for every iteration, this is what you're evaluating:

```
page     $index
0    ==  0      // true
1    ==  1      // true
2    ==  2      // true
```

Instead, what you should do, is add a separate variable to the scope that tracks the current page, if you don't have one already. For illustrative purposes, let's call it `currentPage`. Then you can change your expression to:

```
ng-class="(page === currentPage) ? 'active': ''"
```

Additionally, in your `selectedPage()` function you would update `currentPage` to the page the user selected (i.e. `$scope.currentPage = page`).

Comment: Ahh.  My current page variable is $scope.page.  I didn't even notice that I used the same variable name in the ng-repeat.   Fixed it by changing to ng-repeat="p in pages".